# how to increase the size of existing rootfs folder in Google Compute Engine disk

Tags: google-compute-engine

How to increase the size of the disk in Google Compute Engine after instance is crested .

We have created the instance of VM with 10gb hard disc.Later to increase the disk size we have added a new disk with 200gb to the previous 10gb disk which is up and running. 
we have mounted the 200gb with 10gb disk and it is shown in as /dev/sdb when df -h command is given.

When we tried to run a software , it has filled the rootfs folder of 10 gb  and the installation failed due to low disk space ( the rootfs folder is occupied 100%).

We tried to run **resize2fs** command, but it says that the size is already reached.

the command trace is as below :

***xxxxxxxxx_gmail_c@pgg-2:/home/xxxxx/opt/pgg/scripts$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb
resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
The filesystem is already 52428800 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
xxxxxxxxx_gmail_c@pega-2:/home/xxxxx/opt/pgg/scripts$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb 20G
resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Filesystem at /dev/sdb is mounted on /mnt/pd1; on-line resizing required
resize2fs: On-line shrinking not supported***

Help required in incresing the rootfs size so that we can continue the installation.
Also Can we merge the two disks so that it will treated as 210gb (logically) instead of 10gb + 200gb.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since the VM instance is in production and there are some files and data that need to be protected, the first step is taking a snapshot of the disk. This will create a backup of the disk and can be useful for recreating a persistent disk that might have been damaged or lost.

Creating a disk snapshot can be easily done though Google Developer Console or using the command below:

```
$ gcloud compute disks snapshot DISK
```

After creating snapshot, you can create a larger disk (as an example 200GB) from the snapshot by the command below:

```
$ gcloud compute disks create <newdiskname> --source-snapshot=<my-data-disk-snapshot> --size=200GB
```

Now you can re-partition the new disk by going through ‘Step 3’ to ‘Step 15’ of ‘[Repartitioning a root persistent disk’](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#manualrepartition) artcile. Manual re-partitioning may not be needed for the [GCE operating systems which support automatic resizing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#repartitionrootpd).

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a directory to mount the new disks filesystem at.  You'll probably need to position and format the disk first, then mount the new filesystem and chippy file from the existing drive to the new drive.

Here's a guide on how to do that: 
https://muffinresearch.co.uk/adding-more-disk-space-to-a-linux-virtual-machine/

Depending, you might also want to start over with a larger root drive by following these instructions:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repartitionrootpd

Answer (score 0):

just follow these steps

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#creatingrootpd

I hope it helps.